# After GRUB my PC will only boot Ubuntu after pressing the power button which shuts my pc down

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, shutdown, 32-bit

I successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit on my PC. So I restart my PC which takes me to GRUB. I press enter for Ubuntu but then some line of code appears and then the screen goes black. Pressing the power button after that for some reason starts Ubuntu but then after a few seconds shuts down the PC. How do I fix this issue.

I have a HP Pavilion a1647c.

Comment: How long are you waiting after the screen turns black before pushing the power button? It could be that the Ubuntu loading screen is just not displaying, and you need to wait for a minute or two while it loads. What happens if you press left arrow on the keyboard while screen is black? Does it show you a bunch of lines of console output? If so, that is the loading process going on, you just need to be patient. When you push the power button, try pushing the ESC key right after that and see if it prevents the shutdown (Power button is shortcut key for "Shutdown" in ubuntu, and ESC is "Cancel")

Comment: I have waited for over 10 minutes then press the power button to see Ubuntu automatically start loading. I have not tried that power button then escape thing so I will try that.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of waiting, pressing power then ESC, and pressing all the keys on the keyboard. Pressing ESC cancels Ubuntu from booting instead of canceling the shutdown @blendenzo .

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you meant by "starts Ubuntu". Do you mean it just shows the loading screen, or that it actually brings you to the login screen/desktop? If it is not getting even getting past the loading screen, it may be helpful to see the boot log. Start up the computer with an Ubuntu live cd or usb, then in the file manager find the computer's hard drive and look for the file /var/log/boot.log and post its contents here. It also might be useful to see /var/log/dmesg

Comment: i meant it shows the loading screen

Comment: Okay, so like I said above, it would be helpful to see /var/log/boot.log and /var/log/dmesg from the computer to see where the process is hanging up.